# Red Hat failed to make nodejs

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, make, node.js

When I run the `./configure`, the error occurred.
What does the `This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation` means?

How to make it work?

Environment:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 3) 2.6.32_1-11-0-0
```

Error info:

```
$PYTHON ./configure
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                       'default_configuration': 'Release',
                       'defines': [],
                       'include_dirs': [],
                       'libraries': []},
  'variables': { 'clang': 0,
                 'gcc_version': 46,
                 'host_arch': 'x64',
                 'node_install_npm': 'true',
                 'node_prefix': '',
                 'node_shared_cares': 'false',
                 'node_shared_http_parser': 'false',
                 'node_shared_libuv': 'false',
                 'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
                 'node_shared_v8': 'false',
                 'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
                 'node_tag': '',
                 'node_unsafe_optimizations': 0,
                 'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
                 'node_use_etw': 'false',
                 'node_use_openssl': 'true',
                 'node_use_perfctr': 'false',
                 'node_use_systemtap': 'false',
                 'python': '/home/bae/apps/Python-2.7.6/python',
                 'target_arch': 'x64',
                 'v8_enable_gdbjit': 0,
                 'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/gyp_node.py", line 57, in <module>
    run_gyp(gyp_args)
  File "tools/gyp_node.py", line 18, in run_gyp
    rc = gyp.main(args)
  File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 527, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 503, in gyp_main
    options.circular_check)
  File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 129, in Load
    params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])
  File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2687, in Load
    generator_input_info)
  File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 594, in LoadTargetBuildFilesParallel
    parallel_state.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
  File "/home/bae/apps/Python-2.7.6/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "/home/bae/apps/Python-2.7.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/home/bae/apps/Python-2.7.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 232, in _setup_queues
    from .queues import SimpleQueue
  File "/home/bae/apps/Python-2.7.6/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 48, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock, BoundedSemaphore, Semaphore, Condition
  File "/home/bae/apps/Python-2.7.6/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 59, in <module>
    " function, see issue 3770.")
ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

Comment: Did you read the referenced issue? http://bugs.python.org/issue3770

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Yes, but nothing useful found. Maybe it's too hard for me to understand what they are talking about.

Comment: I couldn't spot anything in there myself. Just thought that maybe some of those configuration directives they mention could be of use.